# Submitting a rails remote true form with query and it's still redirecting/giving 406

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I've spent way too much time on this, trying to figure out why it isn't working. I've tried two methods with flaws in both. It's driving me nuts. Here's my code.
**METHOD 1**

**Form**

```
<%= form_for @order, remote: true do |f| %> 
...
<% end %><br>
```

**Js**

```
$('#new_order').submit(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
      //Some validations
      if (validation successful) {
        $('#new_order')[0].submit();
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }

});
```

**Controller**

```
def create
   #if @order.save, the usual
   respond_to do |format|
      format.js
   end
end
```

Now if there's a format.html there it'll follow the html redirect and if not, it throws a 406 error. It works normally without javascript but it still says html in the header.

**METHOD 2** 
**Form**

```
<%= form_for @order, remote: true do |f| %> 
...
<% end %><br>
```

**Js**

```
$('#new_order').submit(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
      //Some validations
      var form = $(this);
      if (validation successful) {
        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr('action'),
      dataType: "json",
      data: form.serialize(),
      complete: function(js_data){
        alert(js_data);
      }  
  });
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }

});
```

**Controller**

```
def create
   #if @order.save, the usual
   respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @order }
   end
end
```

Now this one works a bit better, no redirection or 406 error but it ignores everything in the complete or success block. Hence the page remains the same even when the order was successfully created.

Nb: This page is a subdomain page. e.g. blog1.mysite.com, but it works without js.
My ideal method is the first method. Is there anyway to force the submit to respond to the format.js? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us any more information on the 406 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually force the request format to respond to js.
Add a before filter in your controller.

```
before_filter :default_format_js, only: :create

def default_format_js
    reponse.headers['content--type'] = 'text/javascript'
    request.format = 'js'
end
```